# How can I compare Transforms data if they are identical and then check if they are null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Inside `OnSelectionChange()` inside a EditorWindow script type:

I want to check if the selected object transform is identical to one of the transforms in test. `selections` is List `test` is array

First I want to check if one of the transforms data in `text` is identical to the selected object transform data. Then In the editor in the hierarchy I'm deleting the object and now it is `null`. Now `selected` is `null`. Now I want to check that if the object is `null` but also was identical in the first check then set a flag to `true` and if it's not `null` or not identical set a flag to `false`.

```
private void OnSelectionChange()
{
    selectionChanged = true;

    var selections = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();
    var test = TransformSaver.LoadTransforms();

    if (selections.Count > 0)
        tempsel = selections;

    if (tempsel.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < tempsel.Count; x++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {
                var selected = tempsel[x];

                if (selected.transform.parent == test[i].parent &&
                    selected.transform.name == test[i].name &&
                    selected.transform.localPosition == test[i].pos &&
                    selected.transform.localRotation == test[i].rot &&
                    selected.transform.localScale == test[i].scale)
                {
                    hasLoaded = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < selections.Count; y++)
        {
            if (selections[y] == null && hasLoaded == true)
            {
                hasLoaded = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The next step is to use the flag to decide if to enable true or false a button inside OnGUI:

```
private void Load()
{
    if (selectionChanged)
    {
        if (hasLoaded == true)
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button("Load"))
    {
        TransformSaver.LoadTransform();
        hasLoaded = false;
    }
}
```

But so far no success.

The main goal logic rules as I see it, Maybe they should be others but this is how I explain what I want to do:

1. To compare the Transforms data between the selections and test.
2. Set a flag to true if the data is identify in one or more of the selections objects against the test array.
3. To check if the one or more of the selections objects are null and if they are null now to check if they were identify in the first check (1).
4. If both selected objects one or more and the test Transforms data one or more are identify and also null only then set another flag to true.
5. Use the new flag if it's true or false to decide if to enable true/false the button "Load"

Last the TransformSaver class that test is getting the Transforms data array from: (I have another button "Save" that save a selection of objects and then I use `LoadTransforms()` to return the array of data of the saved Transforms from the JSON file)

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public static class TransformSaver
 {
     [System.Serializable]
     public class Transform
     {
         public string sceneName;
         public string name;
         public UnityEngine.Transform parent;
         public Vector3 pos;
         public Quaternion rot;
         public Vector3 scale;
     }

     //Save Transform
     public static void SaveTransform(UnityEngine.Transform[] tranformToSave)
     {
         Transform[] trnfrm = new Transform[tranformToSave.Length];
         for (int i = 0; i < trnfrm.Length; i++)
         {
             trnfrm[i] = new Transform();

             trnfrm[i].sceneName = tranformToSave[i].gameObject.scene.name;
             trnfrm[i].name = tranformToSave[i].name;
             trnfrm[i].parent = tranformToSave[i].parent;
             trnfrm[i].pos = tranformToSave[i].localPosition;
             trnfrm[i].rot = tranformToSave[i].localRotation;
             trnfrm[i].scale = tranformToSave[i].localScale;
         }

         string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(trnfrm, true);
         //PlayerPrefs.SetString("transform", jsonTransform);
         File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt", jsonTransform);
     }

     public static Transform[] LoadTransforms()
     {
         string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt");
         if (jsonTransform == null)
         {
             return null;
         }

         Transform[] savedTransforms = JsonHelper.FromJson<Transform>(jsonTransform);

         return savedTransforms;
     }
 }
```